# xdg-open opens chrome but does not load the URL

Tags: 14.04

"xdg-open http://www.google.ca" in a command line opens my default browser(google-chrome) but does not load the URL.

If I change my default browser to Firefox the URL loads just fine.

Any ideas?

I'm running 14.04.

Comment: Can't duplicate... What does `google-chrome http://google.ca` do?

Comment: I use chromium as default browser and it's working fine.

Comment: 'google-chrome http://google.ca' works no problem. However, i'm still unable to have links load properly from other applications that use xdg-open. @Tim

Comment: @RaduRădeanu If i set my default browser to chromium or firefox xdg-open works no problem. This problem is only with chrome.

Comment: If i delete the google-chrome.desktop file from ~/.local/share/applications it works fine. So weird.

Comment: i have done an xdg-open script it is not perfect but it used the data from gconf
http://jeanmichel.gens.free.fr/scripts/xdg-open

Answer (score 13):

It's because the `.desktop` file that Chrome installs in your home (in `~/.local/share/applications`) is bad. Either add a `%U` to the end of the `Exec=` line, like so:

```
Exec=/opt/google/chrome/chrome %U
```

or remove it and let your system pick up the one Chrome itself ships in `/usr/share`.

Comment: edit the default one named `google-chrome.desktop` not the profiles like `chrome-blahblahblah...`